# Can't open a window with a website URL from prompt()

Tags: javascript

I want to create a new window with the website the user has inputted with the open method, but I can't seem to find the answer to the problem.

```
// beginning of input
var input = document.createElement("input")
input.setAttribute("value","Create Window")
input.setAttribute("type","button")
input.id = "input";
document.body.appendChild(input)
// end of input
// beginning of input2
var input2 = document.createElement("input")
input2.setAttribute("value", "close window")
input2.setAttribute("type","button")
input2.id = "input2";
document.body.appendChild(input2)
// end of input2
function createWindow(){
    var prompt0 = prompt("what is the name of the website that you want to go to:")
    open("prompt0","newWindow","height=500,width=400,toolbar=1,titlebar=1,menubar=yes")
}
```

There are no errors but there is no window with the expected result. The expected result is a window with the website that the user has inputted.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the variable incorrectly to `open`, it should not have quotes around it, because that makes it a string.

```
var prompt0 = prompt("what is the name of the website that you want to go to:")
open(prompt0,"newWindow","height=500,width=400,toolbar=1,titlebar=1,menubar=yes")
```